# How do I initialize a variable without initializing it in every rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I think I am at a loss.. i can't wrap my head around this problem.

How can i initialize the variable "cssCompiler" in the Component "CodePreview" without initializing it every rerender? If i put it in a `useEffect` im violating the React Hook rules

**CodePreview**

```
import SassCompiler from './compiler/sass_compiler';
const CodePreview = ({ codeContent, saveSnippet }) => {
    //Init with default values
    const [css, setCss] = useState(codeContent.CSS.code);
    const cssCompiler = useRef(null);
    
    if (codeContent.CSS.mode === 'sass') {
        cssCompiler.current = sass_compiler(css, setCss);
        console.log('Compiler: ', cssCompiler);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (cssCompiler.current) {
            cssCompiler.current.compileSass(codeContent.CSS.code)
        }
    }, [css])
    ...
```

**SassCompiler**

```
import useScript from "../../../../hooks/useScript";
import { useRef } from 'react';
const SassCompiler = (css, setCss) => {
    const compiler = useRef(null);
    useScript('js/libs/sass.js/dist/sass.js', () => {
        compiler.current = new window.Sass();
        compileSass(css)
        console.log('SASS Compiler setted');
    });

    const compileSass = (sass) => {
        try {
            compiler.current.compile(sass, (result) => {
                setCss(result.text);
                console.log('SASS Compiled');
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Err: ', e);
        }
    }
}

export default SassCompiler;
```

**useScript.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = (url, onLoad) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        if (onLoad) script.onload = () => onLoad();

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do anything as `useRef` persists between renders, **its not** constantly getting re-inintialized everytime the component changes.

Comment: So that means even if i get the console.log from the lines

```if (codeContent.CSS.mode === 'sass') {
        cssCompiler.current = sass_compiler(css, setCss);
        console.log('Compiler: ', cssCompiler);
    }```

it doesn't get reinitialized? Because every time something changes, i get the output ```Compiler {current: null}```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize a compiler and never replace it, you can just define it in the module's scope, outside the component.